# How to sort array in the customized order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array, and I would like to out put value on specific order. How I can do this.

**Array**

```
$age = array(48,37,43,56,32);
```

Output I want

```
37
56
43
32
48
```

I have put `array $age` in `foreach` loop. I created another array outside `foreach` loop. I am doing `array Push` if the the `value = xx`. Its not working.

What is the best way so I can have my result coming out in above order.

Comment: I don't understand the ordering logic...what is the magic behind it?

Comment: If the sorting logic is fixed, then your other array *is* the sorted array. If not, you'll need to be clearer about it.

Comment: The best way is `usort` since you can create your own algorithm with it. That said, I wouldn't have a clue what algorithm you used for sorting (?) like that.

Comment: The logic behind this is that each of this age is forign key in another table. so 37 is students, 56 is adults, 43 is disable etccc....So I want to see students first, than adults than disabled etc...

Comment: If you know the order, why do you need this array? Also, using age as a foreign key to "roles" sounds incredibly weird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I understand your question correctly but if you already know the order than what's the purpose of making this array.

Well, I guess I have two solutions to sort this array in your custom order

## Option 1

Specify `$order` array (if it's already known to you) and use `usort` to compare the values of `$age` and `$order` arrays. `usort` will find the items of `$age` within the `$order` array.

```
$order = array(37, 56, 43, 32, 48);
$age = array(48, 37, 43, 56, 32);

usort($age, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $firstItem  = array_search($a, $order);
    $secondItem = array_search($b, $order);

    return $firstItem - $secondItem;
});

print_r($age);
```

> I've used [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
>   in `usort` to make sorting simpler

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 37
    [1] => 56
    [2] => 43
    [3] => 32
    [4] => 48
)
```

> You can check [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and
>   [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

## Option 2

From your comment, I tried to come up with another approach which is setting the keys in `$age` and `$order` arrays and compare both arrays to sort it in custom order.

```
$order = array('students', 'adults', 'disable', 'enable', "variable");
$age = array(
    'variable' => 48,
    'students' => 37,
    'disable' => 43,
    'adults' => 56,
    'enable' => 32
);

$ordered_array = array_merge(array_flip($order), $age);
print_r($ordered_array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [students] => 37
    [adults] => 56
    [disable] => 43
    [enable] => 32
    [variable] => 48
)
```

> Also check
>   [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and
>   [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)